# Convert object of objects to array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

I work on a Angular Project and I have a little issue with an object..

I have an object with objects inside :

```
P3E051V:{
    lot: "P3E051V"
    quantite: 5400
},
P3E052V:{
    lot: "P3E052V"
    quantite: 5400
},
P3E054V:{
    lot: "P3E054V"
    quantite: 10800
}
```

What I would like to do is to display a table like this :
[image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D66N0.png)

But I can't loop on an object with *ngFor.
I tried to use Object.entries(myObject) but it doesn't work.

Anyone have an idea to solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key])...

Comment: `Object.keys(obj)` gives you an array of the keys, `['P3E051V','P3E052V','P3E054V']`. Or you can use `Object.entries`

Comment: You said you've tried `Object.entries(myObject)`, but I get the sneaking suspicion that it worked exactly as it's supposed to, and you just didn't understand what to expect from the output. You should set a breakpoint in your code to figure out what the output of `Object.entries` is, because really it could be the solution you're looking for if you know how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` which will give an array with all the keys inside the object. You can get the objects from the main object object using those keys while using a loop

```js
var obj={P3E051V:{
    lot: "P3E051V",
    quantite: 5400
},
P3E052V:{
    lot: "P3E052V",
    quantite: 5400
},
P3E054V:{
    lot: "P3E054V",
    quantite: 10800
}
}
Object.keys(obj).forEach(e=>console.log(obj[e]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const objs = {P3E051V:{
    lot: "P3E051V",
    quantite: 5400
},
P3E052V:{
    lot: "P3E052V",
    quantite: 5400
},
P3E054V:{
    lot: "P3E054V",
    quantite: 10800
}}

console.log('the key + the object', Object.entries(objs));
console.log('just the internal object', Object.entries(objs).map(o => o[1]));
```

Here's what objectt.entries does

Answer (score 0):

Just put this object into an array
like array.push(object)

Answer (score 0):

```
const inputObject = {
  P3E051V:{
    lot: "P3E051V",
    quantite: 5400
  },
  P3E052V:{
    lot: "P3E052V",
    quantite: 5400
  },
  P3E054V:{
    lot: "P3E054V",
    quantite: 10800
  }
}

const outputObjectArray = Object.entries(inputObject).map(entry=>{ return entry[1]});
console.log(outputObjectArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I try with **Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key])** and it works
Thanks for your help